# Can httpcontext be used in Blazor server mode?

Tags: blazor

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
>
> [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor) must be avoided with interactive rendering because there isn't a valid `HttpContext` available.

but, contains httpcontext code was generated with dotnet -tau {AUTHENTICATION}.
I don't know if I should use httpcontext. This is really confusing me, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It's already set when the SPA starts.

Read on further in the same article:

> HttpContext can be used as a cascading parameter only in statically-rendered root components.

You can only use it when your page is being pre-rendered in the *HttpRequest* pipeline context.

I'm guessing you want to modify it in authentication where you want the login page to be a Blazor Interactive page.

Comment: Thanks Reply, 

httpcontext can still be obtained in interactive pages(`@rendermode InteractiveServer`)
It seems contradictory to the following content.

**HttpContext can be used as a cascading parameter only in statically-rendered root components.**

Comment: Yes, it is available.  But a lot of the functionality it provides isn't.  The advice is sound because you need to know what you can and can't do with it in the Blazor context to use it safely.  All too often people don't and get into trouble: hence the advice.  I use it to detect the render mode.

Comment: thanks, This part is too easy to misunderstand.